# Lazy loading autocomplete datalist angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, autocomplete

I've got a job to refactoring some code to improve preference on `IE 11`,
One of the required improvement is to do some lazy loading for autocomplete input because`IE 11` is little heavy with rendering `array` with 600 items.

I works under some constraints:

```
1. I have 4 hours to done the job (it's mean that there is no time to massive changes)
2. AngularJs version 1.3.1
3. jQuery version 1.6.8
4. The page is hosting on salesforce (it's not changing anything because it's run html and angularjs).
```

Here is a `GIF` of the issue:
[link to GIF](https://i.imagesup.co/images2/fb1b304f3ceec8a3def78ba278586b3ddbe7abc4.gif)

I'm success to do some lazy loading, but for some reason that I don't know to explain it's doesn't  works correctly.
The list of autocomplete rendering only after I out-focus and focus again on the input field.

Here is the **HTML code**:

```html
<input type="text" id="ddProductAutoCompleteInput" name="product" class="selectBoxTom" data-ng-model="item.onlineProd" datalist="t_productsList_DDP" placeholder="All Products"  />
<datalist id="t_productsList_DDP"  size="5" style="overflow-y: scroll">
     <option ng-repeat="prod in productList | limitTo:totalLimit track by $index" value="{{prod.Tapi_Online_Product_Name__c}}" ngc-done="'scope.setAutoCompletProdectDwonloadDoc'"/>
</datalist>
```

And here is the **AngularJs code**:

```
$scope.setAutoCompletProdectDwonloadDoc = function()//sourceList)
 {  
            var flag = true;
            var elem = jQuery("#ddProductAutoCompleteInput");
            var list = jQuery("#t_productsList_DDP");
            $scope.totalLimit = 50;
            jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').scroll(function(){
                if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() + jQuery(this).innerHeight() >= jQuery(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                    $scope.totalLimit += 10;
                    elem.autocomplete.focusout();
                }
            })

            elem.autocomplete({
                source: list.children().map(function(){return jQuery(this).val();}).get(),//sourceList,
                minLength: 0,
                search: function(event,ui){
                    jQuery(this).data("autocomplete").menu.bindings = $();
                },
                select: function (event, ui)
                {
                  var valueP = ui.item.value;
                  flag = false;
                  elem.autocomplete('close');
                  $scope.$apply(function()
                  {
                   $scope.item.onlineProd = valueP;
                   angular.forEach($scope.docTypeList, function(docType){
                                  docType.selected = false});
                   $scope.tempList.length = 0;
                   $scope.filterd = 'false';

                  });
                },
                open:function (event, ui)
                {
                    // Try to select the first one if it's the only one
                    var $children = jQuery(this).data('autocomplete').menu.element.children();
                    if ($children.size() == 1)
                    {
                    }/*else{
                        var item = '';
                        var childs = $children.toArray();
                        for(var i = 0; i< $children.length; i++){

                            if(event.target.value.toLowerCase().trim() === childs[i].innerText.toLowerCase().trim()){
                                item = $children.eq(i);
                            }
                        }
                        if(item !== '')
                            jQuery(this).data('autocomplete').menu.focus(null, item);
                    }*/
                }
            }).focus(function(){
                if (flag)
                {
                    jQuery(this).autocomplete('search',jQuery(this).val())
                    flag = false;
                }else{
                    elem.autocomplete('close');
                    flag = true;
                return false;
                }
            }).focusout(function(){flag = true; return false;})

            $scope.totalLimit = 50;

  };
```

I except that the Lazy Load will works correctly - it's mean that when I scroll down the list - 10 more items will rendering to the list.[enter link description here](https://i.imagesup.co/images2/fb1b304f3ceec8a3def78ba278586b3ddbe7abc4.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Deep reseach that I made I found a solution
Reference for the solution is 
    http://jsfiddle.net/LesignButure/

So the main problem of my issue was that I had to work on existing code and not change it, just add some script on it.

The assmption that the page hasen't rendered was mistaked, coz the life cycle of the autocomplete was - 
1. totalLimit set limit to list
2. setAutoCompletProdectDwonloadDoc is activated and configure the structure of of autocomplete
3. the list is rendered
4. after scrolling down - the totalLimit chagned and the component is rendered but the list not change coz the 'open' function of autocomplete hasent run.
5. after re-clicking on the input field the new list was showen

so the change I made is here:

```
/*product*/
 $scope.setAutoCompletProdectDwonloadDoc = function()//sourceList)
 {
     var flag = true;
     var elem = jQuery("#ddProductAutoCompleteInput");
     var list = jQuery("#t_productsList_DDP");


/**
     elem.autocomplete({
         source: list.children().map(function () { return jQuery(this).val(); }).get(),//sourceList,
         minLength: 0,
         search: function (event, ui) {
             jQuery(this).data("autocomplete").menu.bindings = $();
         },
         select: function (event, ui) {
             var valueP = ui.item.value;
             flag = false;
             elem.autocomplete('close');
             $scope.$apply(function () {
                 $scope.item.onlineProd = valueP;
                 angular.forEach($scope.docTypeList, function (docType) {
                     docType.selected = false
                 });
                 $scope.tempList.length = 0;
                 $scope.filterd = 'false';

             });
         },
         open: function (event, ui) {
             var $children = jQuery(this).data('autocomplete').menu.element.children();
         }
         }).focus(function () {
             if (flag) {
                 jQuery(this).autocomplete('search', jQuery(this).val())
                 flag = false;
             } else {
                 elem.autocomplete('close');
                 flag = true;
                 return false;
             }
         }).focusout(function () { flag = true; return false; })

**/
        elem.autocomplete({
            source: list.children().map(function () { return jQuery(this).val(); }).get(),
            minLength: 0,
            delay: 0,
            search: function (event, ui) {
                jQuery(this).data("autocomplete").menu.bindings = $();
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                 var valueP = ui.item.value;
                 flag = false;
                 elem.autocomplete('close');
                 $scope.$apply(function () {
                     $scope.item.onlineProd = valueP;
                     angular.forEach($scope.docTypeList, function (docType) {
                         docType.selected = false
                     });
                     $scope.tempList.length = 0;
                     $scope.filterd = 'false';

                 });
             },
             open: function (event, ui) {
                 var $children = jQuery(this).data('autocomplete').menu.element.children();
            }
        }).focus(function () {
            //reset result list's pageindex when focus on
            window.pageIndex = 0;
            $(this).autocomplete("search");
        }).focusout(function () { flag = true; return false; });


        $.extend($.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
                _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
                    //remove scroll event to prevent attaching multiple scroll events to one container element
                    $(ul).unbind("scroll");
                    var self = this;
                    self._scrollMenu(ul, items);
                },
                _scrollMenu: function (ul, items) {
                    var maxShow = 999;
                    if(items.length > 400)
                        maxShow = 20;
                    var self = this;
                    var results = [];
                    var pages = Math.ceil(items.length / maxShow);
                    results = items.slice(0, maxShow);

                    if (pages > 1) {
                        $(ul).scroll(function () {
                            if (isScrollbarBottom($(ul))) {
                                ++window.pageIndex;
                                if (window.pageIndex >= pages) return;

                                results = items.slice(window.pageIndex * maxShow, window.pageIndex * maxShow + maxShow);

                                //append item to ul
                                $.each(results, function (index, item) {
                                    self._renderItem(ul, item);
                                });
                                //refresh menu
                                self.menu.deactivate();
                                self.menu.refresh();
                                // size and position menu
                                ul.show();
                                self._resizeMenu();
                                ul.position($.extend({
                                    of: self.element
                                }, self.options.position));
                                if (self.options.autoFocus) {
                                    self.menu.next(new $.Event("mouseover"));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    $.each(results, function (index, item) {
                        self._renderItem(ul, item);
                    });
                }
            });

            function isScrollbarBottom(container) {
                 var height = container.outerHeight();
                 var scrollHeight = container[0].scrollHeight;
                 var scrollTop = container.scrollTop();
                 if (scrollTop >= scrollHeight - height) {
                     return true;
                 }
                 return false;
             };
  };
```